# How to delete extraparams from loaded store sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to delete the extra params after the store is loaded. If I put as '' still it has that param in url and delete is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to delete all of the extraParams, just use this code:

```
store.getProxy().setExtraParams({});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add below code after store load

```
delete store.proxy.extraParams.param_name;
```